# Get through each day between two dates

Tags: php, datetime, while-loop

```
$start_dt = "2019-02-14";
$dt1_obj = new DateTime($start_dt);
$end_dt = "2019-05-05";
$dt2_obj = new DateTime($end_dt);


// get every day from $start_dt date to  $end_dt   
while ( $dt1_obj->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d') <= $end_dt ) {
    $ddd = $dt1_obj;
    echo $ddd->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d');
    echo "\n";  
}
```

This runs in an endless cycle. What is reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a day in the loop condition, and then subtract a day in the loop's body (note that `$ddd` is just another reference to the **same DateTime object**!). You could start a day earlier and print the date itself in the loop:

```
$start_dt = "2019-02-13";
$dt1_obj = new DateTime($start_dt);
$end_dt = "2019-05-05";
$dt2_obj = new DateTime($end_dt);

// get every day from $start_dt date to  $end_dt   
while ( $dt1_obj->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d') <= $end_dt ) {
    echo $dt1_obj->format('Y-m-d');
    echo "\n";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this , it should work.

```
 $start_dt = "2019-02-14"; 
 $end_dt = "2019-05-05"; 
 $period = new DatePeriod(
           new DateTime($start_dt),
           new DateInterval('P1D'),
           new DateTime($end_dt)
 );
```

To get the dates you should iterate

```
 foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
    //$value->format('Y-m-d')       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you add one day then substract one... Try this instead

```
// get every day from $start_dt date to  $end_dt   
while ( $dt1_obj->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d') <= $end_dt ) {
    $ddd = $dt1_obj;
    echo $ddd->format('Y-m-d');
    echo "\n";  
}
```

Comment: While my answer flags what was wrong with yours, the best one should be using a period as D.Khumoyun stated.